# Increased number of cores from 2 to 4 on VMWare VM; Windows reports "two processors"

Tags: vmware-esx

I had a VM with two cores. I powered it down and changed the settings to four cores.

Here's what I see:

- System (right-click on My Computer > Properties) reports "(2 processors)"
- Task Manager shows two CPU core graphs
- Device manager shows four CPUs under Processors
- VMWare reports four CPUs

It seems strange. Am I missing some step to get Windows to use the remaining two CPUs?

I'm running Windows 7 SP1 x64.

Comment: What EXACT version of Windows are you using?

Comment: And what Edition of which Version are you running?

Comment: Windows 7 Professional SP1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've give the VM 4 CPU's, Windows 7 will only deal with two physical CPUs, it'll see more but it's a client OS so only handles 2 at a time.

What you need to do is force it to think it's one CPU with four cores, by the way VMWare Workstation lets you define this on a per-VM basis as it's designed to Client OS based VMs, whereas ESXi is more focussed on the Server related OSs which can handle >2 physical CPUs.

Here's a hack/change to do what you need;

http://www.yellow-bricks.com/2009/06/04/per-processor-licenses-for-your-application/

Comment: This worked with a value of 4.

Comment: Fun fact: this also seems to be an issue in Workstation (12 at least), if you happen to try to change core number from a running VM "on the fly". `numvcpus` is increased properly, but `cpuid.coresPerSocket` doesn't get set accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Most of VMware machines you will find are configured to work with the last free version of VMware Workstation, namely 6. The latter means you have 2 processors limitation. In case you have a license for VMware 6.5+ you can change "hardware compatibility" (as VMware calls it), so that you can add more processors.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you're explicitly setting it in esxi as 2cpu's 2cores each. that will be important as, like the previous poster indicated, windows 7 can't handle more than two cpu's.